# Cannot start my react-native application on Genymotion with expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, genymotion, expo

When I try to start my react-native application on Genymotion, it shows:

> Error running adb: 'Error running app. Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=exp://192.168.56.1:19000 flg=0x10000000 }'

Yet when I tried to start Java application, everything works well. I searched the web I found some tips but nothing.

My environment :

```
'{
    "name": "SnapVendy",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
        "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
    },
   "main": "./node_modules/react-natives cripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
   "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native-scripts start",
        "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
        "android": "react-native-scripts android",
        "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
        "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
    },
    "jest": {
         "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "expo": "^25.0.0",
        "mobx": "^4.1.0",
        "native-base": "^2.3.10",
        "react": "16.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.52.0",
        "react-navigation": "^1.5.8"
    }
}'



Expo packager-info.json :
'{
    "expoServerPort": 19000,
    "packagerPort": 19001,
    "packagerPid": 10380,
    "expoServerNgrokUrl": null,
    "packagerNgrokUrl": null,
    "ngrokPid": null
}'
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks !,